# VB.NET make method of object accessible only for certain other object

Tags: vb.net, object, scope

I have declared 2 classes: A and B. They are connected as an object tree: Object A holds a "list of B" as private member variable.

```
EDIT: I am declaring 3 classes: A, B and C. A holds list of B and B holds list of C.
```

All my object data is stored in a database (1 table per object).
Each object has a method "delete", which will delete his own database record ("suicide").
B.delete should only be called from A which will then also remove the item from his own "list of B".

I want, that method B.delete can **only** be invoked internally or by a member of object A.

```
EDIT: and C.delete can only be invoked internally or by a member of object B.
```

However other methods in B and C must remain public.

Is this possible?

What would be the declaration / approach / architecture?

Comment: I think that the only way you could do that would be to declare the two types in their own assembly and declare that method `Friend`. That makes it effectively `Public` inside the same assembly but `Private` outside it. That's how it works with situations like the `DataRow` class constructor. The only way you can create a `DataRow` is to call `NewRow` on a `DataTable` and that invokes a constructor that is inaccessible to you because you're outside the System.Data.dll assembly.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer! To me, as somebody who is not so proficient in understanding the intricacies of assemblies (I should know better as a vb.net programmer) this sounds a bit complicated config mgmt wise. Right?

Comment: It's complicated.  You simply add a class library project to the same solution as application and then reference it from the application project.  You can even use the same namespace in both.  The application will then be able to access all public types and members in the library. That said, the types in the library won't have access to the types in the application, so that may mean that you have to move more types out into another library. It does add complexity and that can be daunting if you're new to it but it's not really complicated. You just need to plan a bit.

Comment: Thanks again. But if I add levels to the tree (like A->B->C) I couldn't hide C.delete from A, because all delete methods are declared "friend". Correct?

Comment: I meant to say "it's not complicated" in my previous comment. Basically, `Friend` means "same assembly only" so use it if you want same assembly only.  If your class relationships get complex then it may not be possible to do what you want that way.

Comment: Thought so. Thanks however! And good to know what you told me.

Comment: You can make it more complicated to execute the delete instead. You can have a soft delete that just sets a flag or put the item in a "deleted" list. Then, you have the database delete that needs a database transaction object as parameter which is only generated in A.

Comment: It looks like this topic is similar to my question, using a different architecture: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1040149/is-there-a-way-to-make-a-value-accessible-only-to-the-parent-of-a-nested-class-v?rq=1